# Congeniality between imputation model and analysis model

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

I have a question about congeniality between imputation model and analysis model. Suppose:

**Research goal:** To estimate the prevalence of disease A among a population as well as among different subpopulations defined by age, sex, age*sex, income, and education.

**Data:** A random sample from the target population, with some missing values in disease A

**Handling of missing data:** Impute missing data in disease A using multiple imputation (e.g., FCS/joint modelling).

**Question:**

1. Should age, sex, age*sex, income, and education be included as predictors in the imputation model?

**Some thoughts:** I was thinking that my substantive analysis model is conceptually equivalent to a logistic regression, with disease A as the outcome and all the other variables which are used to define subgroups as predictors. Therefore, from the perspective of congeniality, it seems reasonable that imputation model MUST include all these variables (age, sex, age*sex, income, and education) from the logistic regression model.

Thank you in advance for your help! :)